# Magento login customer programatically without password

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to try customer login problematically by using below code.

```
 $id =1;
 $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
 $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($id);
 $session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
```

but it doesn't work for me .

do Any one have Idea?

I am using magento 1.9

Comment: you can approve this answer if it is useful....so other people can use this code and solve problem using this.

Answer (score 3):

Try this below code :

```
$email = 'example@email.com';
 $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
 $customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
 $customer->loadByEmail(trim($email));
 Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->loginById($customer->getId());
```